# Title cannot contain "../.."

Tags: support, question-titles

I wrote the question [alias for cd ../..](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529424/alias-for-cd) and it doesn't accept the title: the `..` at the end always disappears.

Bug or feature?

FYI: also applies to this Meta question.

Comment: Tried quoting the title? I'd guess feature, considering the tendency of people to write ???? and ....

Comment: It seems to be ok if `../..` is put in quotation marks (see edited title)

Comment: I know, since I did test that as out [an edit](http://meta.askubuntu.com/revisions/12050/3) (and your edit overwrote my edit). :)

Comment: I was going to test it, but my tests didn't meet the base quality standards for the site.  That moment when automated quality checks backfire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bit of automated rewriting on titles, that strip punctuation other than question marks (and removes spaces before punctuation marks, too). While most of the time this goes largely unnoticed (when a title “help me i cant read my file!!!!! urgent!!!!!” gets posted as “help me i cant read my file!!!!! urgent”), it does occasionally misfire when the punctuation has a technical meaning as in your case.

However, resolution is easy in your case: you aren't trying to create an alias for `cd../..`, you're trying to create an alias called `cd../..`. Hence my proposed title: “Can I use cd../.. as an alias name?”